# Where can find x86.obj?

Tags: object

When I debug C++ file of open source, the error message show that:

error 1 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft DirectX SDK (June2010)\Lib\x86.obj'

The directory of Microsoft Directx sure have no file called 'x86.obj'.
So, what is the x86.obj? Where can I get it?

The platform I use is Visual Studio 2010.

I think the obj file maybe is a combine of .lib file... because in the path, I only see the lib file under the directory of /x86, so I guess: 
The C++ use x86.obj, but it just means that it use lib file under /x86 directory.
So, is there any way to let many .lib file turn to one .obj file?

Any advising appreciate!

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the SDK?

Comment: I'll try, but anyone also use Microsoft DirectX SDK(June2010) and find the file x86.obj in the directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution!

I try to search the text "pragma" all the file, and found what lib the C++ use, and I add it to the linker with whole path like: C:/Program Files/Microsoft DirectX SDK (June 2010)/Lib/x86/dxguid.lib

So, there is no x86.obj file! But if someone face the likely problem, remember to search (crl+F)"pragma", and check what lib you use and add to linker with whole path. Sometimes, the linker can not understand whether the "path" is directory or a lib file, so it occur errors.

Thanks for everyone!